# Android java : Anonymous sign in with Firebase always fails

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I was working with firebase to load images from Firebase realtime database into a `RecyclerView` and then download the selected image into the phone from Firebase Storage. I don't want every one to be able to see the images only if  he is signed in using the anonymous sign in methode, so I've made the storage rules like this:

```js
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read : if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The database rules :

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

I did that, it worked on my 1st app.  I wanted to make a 2nd one, so I copied every thing, renamed databases names and storage names.. but the in the log I get this:

```js
error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    User does not have permission to access this object.
     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
    Could not open resulting stream.
    java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
```

The code I used in order to sign in Anonymously :

```js
private void signInAnonymously() {
        mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Log.e("TAG", "success sign");
                // do your stuff
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "failed sign");
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sign();
    }

    private void sign() {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            Log.e("TAG", "already sign");
        } else {
            signInAnonymously();
            Log.e("TAG", "sign null");
        }
        //loadIntAdd();
    }
```

The code I used to download selected image :

```js
StorageReference  sr = mStorageRef.child("images/img" +selected_img_num + ".png");
                    sr.getBytes(1024 * 1024).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                          //I save the image here
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(final_treatement.this, R.string.oper_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
```

My dependencies :

```js
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My manifest file :

```js
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".choose_image">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".final_treatement"/>
```

note that i've activated anonymous sign in in firebase console

I don't know why it worked before and failed here

Please reply if any thing is missing

Comment: In which place are you gettiong the data from Firebase Storage, in onCreate?

Comment: yes, i download the image from onCreate()

Answer (score 2):

The problem might not be in your code, make sure you have turned on anonymous sign in from the firebase console 
Steps :

1. Go to Authentication in firebase console.
2. Select Tab Sign-in Methods
3. Enable the last option "Anonymous"
4. You are all set :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you are trying to access a file while you are not authenticated yet. Because the Firebase Storage security rules are set to allow only authenticated users, Firebase servers deny your attempt. To solve this, make sure you are first authenticated and then get the images you want. Remember, `onCreate()` method is called before `onStart()`, according to the [life-cycle of the activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Comment: Thanks, i get it now. Should I reverse the operation. Authenticating in onCreate then downloading in onStart(). Can I authenticate in the previous activity, then download in the next one ?.

Comment: Yes, but there is no mandatory place where you should add as long as you respect the order of execution.

Comment: Thanks bro, I really appreciate your answer. But, why it worked on my 1st app ?. Both 1st app and 2nd one have the same code, diffrent firebase projects, databases and storages, I'm confused

Comment: I really cannot say why it worked on your first app without seeing the code but can you confirm that is working now?

Comment: yes I confirm. my 1st app is working right now. Both apps have the same code, but me 2nd can't sign in anonymously while my 1st can. it fails in the 2nd

Comment: The error should be either because of the rules or because of the code that is not the same.

Comment: One more thing to notice here is that when I change the rules to public, allow read if true, everything works properly,

Comment: I understand. Have you tried to use instead of this line of code `allow read : if request.auth != null;` this one `allow read : if request.auth.id != null;`?

Comment: yes i've just did but nothing happend. It still gives the error in the log, can't sign in user anonymously, the problem is here in the sign in I don't know why, but i'll try creating a new firebase project. Thanks for the help